# How can I let language server watch the `Untitled-1` file change?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am creating a language server and watch the `javascript` file changes. Below is the code to register the file type.

```
const clientOptions = {
    // Register the server for plain text documents
    documentSelector: [
      { scheme: 'file', language: 'plaintext' },
      { scheme: 'file', language: 'javascript' },
    ],
    synchronize: {
      // Notify the server about file changes to '.clientrc files contain in the workspace
      fileEvents: vscode.workspace.createFileSystemWatcher('**/*')
    }
  };
```

The `onDidChangeContent` on server side is not triggered about for the file titled with `Untitled-1` which was created temporally on vscode. How can I listen on this file change?

Comment: If it is still named "untitled" then it isn't a file yet.  Not until you save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try registering for the `untitled` scheme along with the `file` scheme:

```
const clientOptions = {
    documentSelector: [
      { scheme: 'file', language: 'plaintext' },
      { scheme: 'file', language: 'javascript' },
      { scheme: 'untitled', language: 'plaintext' },
      { scheme: 'untitled', language: 'javascript' },
    ],
    ...
  };
```

That should let the host know to send your server new, untitled files that have not been saved to disk yet. You can also optional omit the `scheme` entirely if you want to sync all `javascript` and `plaintext` files.